# How do I make a brownie chip?

Tags: brownies

There were some oreo chips in the 100 calorie bags that were very good (they have since ruined the recipe) but I liked the taste/texture of them.

I want to figure out a way to get the same texture, with the flavor of a milk chocolate brownie.  How do you get something that is very much like a cracker (not quite as flaky, but not soft and chewy).  Think Cheez-it crunch, and milk chocolate brownie flavor......

I've tried spreading the same batter over a larger surface, but it never produces that crisp texture.

When I cook brownies, the first part to be eaten is always the crunchy edge (usually by me), I just want a way to make a whole brownie recipe more crunchy.

What do you have to do to get that?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you would want to do is reduce the amount of fat in the recipe, as there is no way to get fat to dry out (well, except by using n-zorbit). Maybe use more cocoa powder and less chocolate, and skip or reduce any butter or other fats. Add more water or skim milk as needed to get a spreadable batter. Then proceed as you are currently doing, baking it as thin as possible. I would aim for a longer time at a lower temperature as that will produce more even baking, instead of only crisp at the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Would leaving the baking soda (or baking powder) out work? Last week, I made a batch of molasses cookies, but forgot the baking soda, and (when cooked fairly thin) they seemed to have the texture/slight crunch you're looking for.

Comment: Have you tried making the brownies, then thinly slicing them and laying them out to dry either in a dehydrator or in a 180°F oven?